# My angular app, does not recognize my model, how can I make it recognize my model?

Tags: angular

I have a MongoDb backend, and I am working on my angular frontend.

I have this Model:

```
 export class Developer {
    public _id: string;
    public name: string;
    public age: number;

    constructor(_id: string, name: string, age: number){
        this._id = _id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public get _name(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
    public set _name(n : string ){
        this.name = n;
    }
    public get _age(): number {
        return this.age;
    }
    public set _age(n: number){
        this.age = n;
    }
}
```

And I also have this function:

```
developers: Developer[] = [];

  onCreate(name, age){
    name = name.value();
    age= age.value();
    a: Developer;
    a._name(name);
    a._age(age);
    this.developers.push(a);
  }
```

And this is the error, I get because of this function:
[image]

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You're apparently writing TypeScript code inside a .js file. TypeScript files should have a .ts extension.

Comment: I believe its the dependecy injections, angular won't know how to create instance of `string` and `number` params

Comment: Wouw thank you! stupid mistake of me @JBNizet

Comment: @xyz thank you man, this was my second mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the file as a .ts file instead of .js . Try saving it as a .ts file

**`developer.ts`**